# How to implement notification handler in WatchOS 2.0?

Tags: watchkit, uilocalnotification, apple-watch, watchos-2, unusernotificationcenter

In [`handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:`'s docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/1619516-handleactionwithidentifier), this method is declared that deprecated **from WatchOS 2.0**

I looked for `App Programming Guide for watchOS`, at [Notification section](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html), they suggest using [UNUserNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter) of [UserNotifications](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications?language=objc) framework. But this framework does **require WatchOS >= 3.0**

How do my app adapt to WatchOS 2.0 user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For WatchOS 2.0 you have to implement the deprecated method `handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:`. The method has been deprecated with the introduction of the `UserNotifications` framework. As this framework is not available on WatchOS before 3.0, the deprecated method is the way to go for older versions.

Comment: they do show this method deprecated from watch os 2.0, not 3.0. I may check different version of the method, could you provide a link?

Comment: No they do not. The documentation states that the methods is available from 2.0 to 3.0. The "to"-version is when the method was deprecated. Check `- (void)setStatusBarStyle:(UIStatusBarStyle)statusBarStyle animated:(BOOL)animated;` for example: The documentation shows its available from 2.0 to 9.0. It was deprecated in 9.0.
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1622923-setstatusbarstyle

Comment: You can also take a look at the NS_DEPRECATED_IOS Macro used to deprecate methods as a reference.

 "The NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 6_0) macro has two version numbers. The first number is when the method was introduced, and the second is when it was deprecated."

http://iosdevelopertips.com/best-practices/eveything-you-need-to-know-about-ios-and-os-x-deprecated-apis.html